# Simple Math & Simple Show // Hide Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

***Hi.***

So iam learning angular and i built a cartservice which calculates total item price.
but now iam stuck on displaying discounts.

What i want to achieve: Displaying 2 different Discounts. but i just cant calculate it correctly ( tried implement simple math in my function didnt worked.)

So:

```
<h1>TOTAL: {{total}}</h1>
      <p *ngIf="total > 200" >DISCOUNT 10% NEW PRICE  </p>

      <p *ngIf="total > 500" >DISCOUNT 20% NEW PRICE </p>
```

**How can i hide the first P if its over 500 ? atm both will be displayed**

my total is calculated this way in a cart service module:

```
 calculatePrice(){
let calcPrice: number = 0;
for(let item of this.items){
  calcPrice += item.price;
}

return calcPrice; }
```

// Here i tried to add simple math before returning like calcprice / 100 * 90. not working
**so how can i output the new total ?**

Answer (score 0):

change it with:

```
<h1>TOTAL: {{total}}</h1>
  <p *ngIf="total < 500;else show_major_500" >DISCOUNT 10% NEW PRICE  </p>

  <ng-template #show_major_500> <p>DISCOUNT 20% NEW PRICE </p></ng-template>
```

The first paragraph will be shown only if total is less than 500; if it is over 500 the second discount is shown

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, that is pretty straight forward, just add the additional condition to the `*ngIf`. You would probably also want to change the condition to `>=`right? So it should look like this:

```
<p *ngIf="total >= 200 && total < 500" >DISCOUNT 10% NEW PRICE  </p>
<p *ngIf="total >= 500" >DISCOUNT 20% NEW PRICE </p>
```

For the second part, you should be able to also do it with some simple conditions and simple math:

```
calculatePrice(){
  let calcPrice: number = 0;
  for(let item of this.items){
    calcPrice += item.price;
  }

  if (calcPrice >= 200 && calcPrice < 500) {
    return Math.round(calcPrice * 90) / 100
  } else if(calcPrice >= 500) {
    return Math.round(calcPrice * 80) / 100
  }
  return calcPrice; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot. yes could have thought of && i mean i know it already and also the if else things but just couldnt connect it properly. in my head. the only Issue is now if the customer buys for like 550 then it calculates down to 440´which is 20% thats right but then the 20% <p> isnt displayed, the 10% will be displayed ^^

Comment: Just use two different values for it (something like total and finalPrice) ...